# Start and End DateTimePickerCtrl in WinApi/WTL

Tags: winapi, mfc, atl, wtl

I have two DateTimePicker Controls  in Win Api/WTL/ATL, the first represents a start date and the second one represents the end date, how can I restrict the date selected on the second one to be 'later' than the one selected in the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controls send "standard" [`DTN_DATETIMECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notifications on value changes. So you need to handle those from both controls and adjust values appropriately, e.g. updating the value of the other control so that "start < stop" at all times.